# How do I reset my theorem count (using mdtheorem)?

Tags: theorems, mdframed

```
%   define environments with counters
\mdtheorem[style=mpdframe,  style=wide      ,%
                        style=greyfr    ,%
                        style=wideln    ]   {discuss}{Discuss Topic}    
\mdtheorem[style=mpdframe,  style=wide      ,%
                        style=greyfr    ,%
                        style=sqzblw    ,%
                        style=wideln    ]   {disc}{Discussion}
```

I want to reset my mdtheorem counter `{disc}` for each chapter. Can someone advise how and where — i.e. in preamble or in document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a trailing optional argument will do:

```
\mdtheorem[
  style=mpdframe,
  style=wide,
  style=greyfr,
  style=wideln,
]{discuss}{Discuss Topic}[chapter]
\mdtheorem[
  style=mpdframe,
  style=wide,
  style=greyfr,
  style=sqzblw,
  style=wideln,
]{disc}{Discussion}[chapter]
```

If you want to remove the chapter number (but I can't understand why), add

```
\renewcommand{\thediscuss}{\arabic{discuss}}
\renewcommand{\thedisc}{\arabic{disc}}
```

Comment: This is useful @egreg. It has the desired effect, yet also produces an unwanted side-effect. Elsewhere, I have set section headings to output without chapter numbers, thus chapter two, section three, is `Section 3`, not `Section 2.3`. In resetting `mdtheorem` as per your suggestion, the side-effect is that is now gives the theorem number as 2.1 etc. I want simply 1, 2, 3 etc, without the chapter number prefiguring. Can you advise further?

Comment: @johnbrc I added the relevant information

Comment: Thank you. FWIW, I want to do this because I am using `mdtheorem` to increase the count applied to discussions, which mirror topics (sections) in a textbook aimed at (non-academic) students. Thus Discussion 3 relates to Topic 3. It is really in the name of simplicity, rather than absolute clarity.